# Is there a text-only equivalent (no curses) of `zenity --question`?

Tags: shell, command-line, shell-script, utilities, user-interface

For my mercurial commit hook, I want to run my test cases and be asked whether I really want to commit if any of the tests fail.  I'm thinking something like `<run-the-tests> || <ask-yes-no>` is the way to go, except I don't know what to put in the `<ask-yes-no>` spot.

My best solution so far is `zenity --question`, but I would like something that doesn't depend on X11.  Then there's `dialog`, but that depends on curses which is a no-go inside an emacs shell.  So, I'm pretty stumped.  How do I turn a yes-or-no user input into a zero-or-nonzero exit status?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/226703/how-do-i-prompt-for-input-in-a-linux-shell-script

Answer (score 3):

```
$ (read -p "Foo the bar? [y/N] " ans ; [ "$ans" = Y -o "$ans" = y ]) ; echo $?
Foo the bar? [y/N] Y
0
```